# Android issue- can't check if a file exists

Tags: java, android, file

I've seen several ways to check if a file exists using the `File.exists()` method. My problem is that I'm using this method and it's throwing a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. I've tried debugging and every time just crashes because it's one of the first checks in my app.

This is the error I'm getting when running my test:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.user.project.MainActivity.isExistingUser(MainActivity.java:36)
    at com.example.user.project.ExampleUnitTest.isNewUser(ExampleUnitTest.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

This code runs when the app is started

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    File passFile;
    private Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpContext();
        setupFile(context);
        //Checks if the password already exists
        if (!isExistingUser()){
            //If the user hasn't used the app before, takes them to the makeID activity
            Intent createIntent = new Intent(this, makeId.class);
            startActivity(createIntent);
        }

    }
```

This function is the function when the app loads, it checks if a user exists or not not and if not it pushes them to create a login.

```
private void setUpContext() {
    context = getApplicationContext();
}
```

This function sets up the context object with the application context.

```
private void setupFile(Context c) {
    passFile = new File(c.getFilesDir(),"pass.txt");
}
```

This function uses the context to get the directory the app is stored in and adds the `.txt` extension for the file.

```
public boolean isExistingUser() {
    return passFile.exists();
}
```

This function is set up to see if the passFile exists as a check to see if the user has already run the app before or not. This is the function that is giving me the exception from above.

This is my first Android app so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace associated with this exception.

Comment: First I'd advise reading the Documentation on Context again. Context.getFilesDir() opens up the path to the App's private file system. Have you created the file? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()

Afterward you then have to use openFileOutput(String, int) and create the file. It's not demonstrated or stated if the file first off is created this way. If you did this way, then disregard this comment. It seems to me this may be an issue first. You could also try using `Environment`and store it on the external or internal memory elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`passFile` is `null`, and so you are crashing with a `NullPointerException`.

You point out that you initialize `passFile` in `setupFile()`. While true, you may not be calling that from `ExampleUnitTest` and its `isNewUser()` method.